# What is wrong with my dice rolling program?

Tags: python, dice

I am new to python and I am trying to make a basic dice rolling program but when I run the program, it never displays the dice picture. The picture is the thing that looks like a die, I am not trying to import pictures. Here is my code

```
leaveprogram = 0
from random import randint
uniform = 0
random = 0
while leaveprogram != "q":
    print ("Dice Rolling Program")
    print ("press enter to roll")
    input()
    number = randint(1, 6)
if number == 1:
    print("[-----------]")
    print("[           ]") 
    print("[     o     ]")
    print("[           ]")
    print("[-----------]")
    leaveprogram=input()
if number == 2:
    print ("[-----------]")
    print ("[           ]")
    print ("[    o o    ]")
    print ("[           ]")
    print ("[-----------]")
    leaveprogram=input()
if number == 3:
    print ("[-----------]")
    print ("[    o o    ]")
    print ("[     o     ]")
    print ("[           ]")
    print ("[-----------]")
    leaveprogram=input()
if number == 4:
    print ("[-----------]")
    print ("[    o o    ]")
    print ("[    o o    ]")
    print ("[           ]")
    print ("[-----------]")
    leaveprogram=input()
if number == 5:
    print ("[-----------]")
    print ("[  o     o  ]")
    print ("[     o     ]")
    print ("[  o     o  ]")
    print ("[-----------]")
    leaveprogram=input()
if number == 6:
    print ("[-----------]")
    print ("[  o     o  ]")
    print ("[  o     o  ]")
    print ("[  o     o  ]")
    print ("[-----------]")
    leaveprogram=input()
```

Comment: Your indentation is wrong.

Comment: Specifically, you need to indent all those `if` statements so they execute in the `while` loop.

Comment: your `if` statements should be inside the while loop ( indented correctly ). Also you don't need multiple `print`s to do that. you can use `print(''' stuff here with line breaks ''')`. the triple quotes allows multiple line string in `print` function.

Comment: Thank your @WarrenWeckesser, but when I indent all  "if" statements then double indent all of the ones bellow that until the next "if" statement, is says "unindent does not match any other indentation level".

Comment: Be sure you are using consistent indentation, and don't mix tabs and spaces.  Take a look at the answers given so far.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the helpful tips

Answer (score 0):

In python, the indentation dictates the scope of the loop or the conditional.
Your if statements should be indented like so:

```
leaveprogram = 0
from random import randint
uniform = 0
random = 0
while leaveprogram != "q":
    print ("Dice Rolling Program")
    print ("press enter to roll")
    input()
    number = randint(1, 6)
    if number == 1:
        print("[-----------]")
        print("[           ]") 
        print("[     o     ]")
        print("[           ]")
        print("[-----------]")
        leaveprogram=input()
. . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct indentations, and also you don't need to get input for `leaveprogram` in every `if` condition.

```
from random import randint
leaveprogram = 0
uniform = 0
random = 0
while leaveprogram != "q":
    print ("Dice Rolling Program")
    print ("press enter to roll")
    leaveprogram=input()
    number = randint(1, 6)
    if number == 1:
        print("[-----------]")
        print("[           ]") 
        print("[     o     ]")
        print("[           ]")
        print("[-----------]")
    if number == 2:
        print ("[-----------]")
        print ("[           ]")
        print ("[    o o    ]")
        print ("[           ]")
        print ("[-----------]")
    if number == 3:
        print ("[-----------]")
        print ("[    o o    ]")
        print ("[     o     ]")
        print ("[           ]")
        print ("[-----------]")
    if number == 4:
        print ("[-----------]")
        print ("[    o o    ]")
        print ("[    o o    ]")
        print ("[           ]")
        print ("[-----------]")
    if number == 5:
        print ("[-----------]")
        print ("[  o     o  ]")
        print ("[     o     ]")
        print ("[  o     o  ]")
        print ("[-----------]")
    if number == 6:
        print ("[-----------]")
        print ("[  o     o  ]")
        print ("[  o     o  ]")
        print ("[  o     o  ]")
        print ("[-----------]")
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the indentation problem, you might want to refactor your code by creating an array of strings, one for each die, and replacing the cascade of `if` statements by a single line of code. One way to do so is to take advantage of Python triple-quoted string literals, as well as the `split()` method:

```
diceString = """
***************
[-----------]
[           ] 
[     o     ]
[           ]
[-----------]
***************
[-----------]
[           ]
[    o o    ]
[           ]
[-----------]
***************
[-----------]
[    o o    ]
[     o     ]
[           ]
[-----------]
***************
[-----------]
[    o o    ]
[    o o    ]
[           ]
[-----------]
***************
[-----------]
[  o     o  ]
[     o     ]
[  o     o  ]
[-----------]
***************
[-----------]
[  o     o  ]
[  o     o  ]
[  o     o  ]
[-----------]"""

die = diceString.split("\n***************\n")
```

This has the nice side effect of making `die[0]` an empty string, so that the strings that you are interested in start at index 1 and always correspond to the number on the die. If you go this route, then that entire cascade of `if` statements can be replaced by the single line:

```
print(die[number])
```